# Liberar memoria en medio lista enlazada

Tags: c

Estoy realizando una función en el que elimine los datos de una lista enlazada dependiendo de un código.

No tengo ningún problema para eliminar el primer elemento. El problema viene cuando elimino los que no son los primeros porque al parecer sí los elimino, pero al imprimirlos me siguen apareciendo (no con los mismos datos, pero la memoria parece que sigue reservada en la lista).

¿Tengo algún error en la función `eliminarDato`? Estoy programando en Linux, ¿puede ser debido a un error en la función `free`?

Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Nodo{
    int codigo;
    char nombre[20];
    char telefono[10];
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
}Persona;

typedef struct Lista{
    Persona *cabecera;
}Listin;

void insertarDatos(int, char[], char[], Listin *);
void imprimirDatos(Listin);
int eliminarDato(int, Listin *);

int main()
{
    Listin miListin, miListin2;
    miListin.cabecera = NULL;
    insertarDatos(5, "Luisa", "555654321", &miListin);
    insertarDatos(10, "Antonio", "555123456", &miListin);
    insertarDatos(14, "Pedro", "555555555", &miListin);
    insertarDatos(17, "Sofía", "555666777", &miListin);
    insertarDatos(23, "Andrea", "555101010", &miListin);
    imprimirDatos(miListin);

    miListin2 = miListin;
    printf("\n¿Se ha eliminado el 14 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(14, &miListin2));
    printf("¿Se ha eliminado el 5 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(5, &miListin2));
    printf("¿Se ha eliminado el 23 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(23, &miListin2));
    printf("¿Se ha eliminado el 11 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(11, &miListin2));
    imprimirDatos(miListin2);
    return 0;
}

void insertarDatos(int codigo, char nombre[20], char telf[10], Listin *listinEjemplo){
    Persona *aux;
    aux = malloc(sizeof(Persona));
    aux->codigo = codigo;
    strcpy(aux->nombre, nombre);
    strcpy(aux->telefono, telf);
    aux->siguiente = listinEjemplo->cabecera;
    listinEjemplo->cabecera = aux;
}

void imprimirDatos(Listin listinEjemplo){
    int i;
    Persona *aux;
    aux = listinEjemplo.cabecera;
    printf("Elementos de la lista:\n");
    for(i = 0; aux != NULL; i++){
        printf("%d. %s (%s)\n", aux->codigo, aux->nombre, aux->telefono);
        aux = aux->siguiente;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    printf("Número de elementos: %d\n", i);
}

int eliminarDato(int codigo, Listin *listinEjemplo){
    int i, j, eliminado = 0;
    Persona *aux, *aux2;
    aux = listinEjemplo->cabecera;
    for(i = 0; aux != NULL && aux->codigo != codigo; i++){
        aux = aux->siguiente;
    }
    if(aux != NULL){
        if(i == 0){ //Elimina primer elemento de la lista
            listinEjemplo->cabecera = aux->siguiente;
            free(aux);
            eliminado = 1;
        }else{ //Elimina elementos del medio o del final de la lista
            aux2 = listinEjemplo->cabecera;
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
                aux2 = aux2->siguiente;
            }
            aux2->siguiente = aux->siguiente;
            free(aux);
            eliminado = 1;
        }
    }
    return eliminado;
}
```

Esta es la ejecución del programa:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

He introducido algunas variaciones en tu código. La forma que tenías de realizar la eliminación de los nodos no era correcta. Te he introducido una forma de hacerlo que utiliza un único puntero para recorrer la lista y uno temporal para contener la dirección del elemento a eliminar una vez se haya encontrado. Te lo pongo a continuación. He introducido las macros `CHARS_NOMBRE` y `CHARS_TELEFONO` para no trabajar con "número mágicos".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHARS_NOMBRE      20
#define CHARS_TELEFONO    10

typedef struct Nodo {
    int codigo;
    char nombre[CHARS_NOMBRE];
    char telefono[CHARS_TELEFONO];
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} Persona;

typedef struct Lista{
    Persona *cabecera;
} Listin;

void insertarDatos(int, const char*, const char*, Listin&);
void imprimirDatos(Listin&);
int eliminarDato(int, Listin&);

int main()
{
    Listin miListin;
    miListin.cabecera = NULL;
    insertarDatos(5, "Luisa", "555654321", miListin);
    insertarDatos(10, "Antonio", "555123456", miListin);
    insertarDatos(14, "Pedro", "555555555", miListin);
    insertarDatos(17, "Sofía", "555666777", miListin);
    insertarDatos(23, "Andrea", "555101010", miListin);
    imprimirDatos(miListin);

    printf( "\n" );
    printf("¿Se ha eliminado el 14 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(10, miListin));
    printf("¿Se ha eliminado el 5 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(5, miListin));
    printf("¿Se ha eliminado el 23 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(23, miListin));
    printf("¿Se ha eliminado el 11 con éxito? %d\n", eliminarDato(11, miListin));
    printf( "\n" );
    
    imprimirDatos(miListin);
    
    return 0;
}

void insertarDatos(int codigo, const char* nombre, const char* telf, Listin& listinEjemplo) {
    Persona *aux;
    aux = (Persona *)malloc(sizeof(Persona));
    
    if (aux) {
        aux->codigo = codigo;
        strncpy(aux->nombre, nombre, sizeof(aux->nombre));
        strncpy(aux->telefono, telf, sizeof(aux->telefono));
        aux->siguiente = listinEjemplo.cabecera;
        listinEjemplo.cabecera = aux;
    }
}

void imprimirDatos(Listin& listinEjemplo){
    int i;
    Persona *aux;
    aux = listinEjemplo.cabecera;
    printf("Elementos de la lista:\n");
    for(i = 0; aux != NULL; i++){
        printf("%d. %s (%s)\n", aux->codigo, aux->nombre, aux->telefono);
        aux = aux->siguiente;
    }
    printf("Número de elementos: %d\n", i);
}

int eliminarDato(int codigo, Listin& listinEjemplo){
    int eliminados = 0;
    struct Nodo **aux;
    aux = &listinEjemplo.cabecera;
    
    // Eliminar el primer elemento que tengan el código: codigo
    while (*aux != NULL) {
        struct Nodo *nodo = *aux;

        if (codigo == nodo->codigo) {
            *aux = nodo->siguiente;
            free(nodo);
            return true;
        } else {
            aux = &((*aux)->siguiente);
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que al finalizar el programa no se libera la memoria de los nodos que no se han eliminado. Si compilas este programa en Linux y lo ejecutas con [valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/info/tools.html) te señalará *memory leaks*.